# how to assign value to input function using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to code a basic login web program with javascript when I discovered a problem. I can't assign value to input function using js. So now I can't use if else to create a basic login. here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Input username" id="username" name="username" class="a47">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Input password" id="password" name="password" class="a47">
        <br>
        <button type="button" onclick="login()" class="login">Login</button>

        <script>
            let username = 'username';
            let password = 'password';

            function login() {
                if (username == a88, password == a89) {
                    alert("Thành công")
                }
                else {
                    alert("Không thành công")
                }
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

please help me

Comment: Use defer in script tag or place script tag at the bottom.

Comment: Can you specify where the variables `a88` & `a89` are coming from?

Comment: variables a88 and a89 come from file index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the input values are not being read from the page. In order to read the input values, you will first be required to grab the `input` DOM elements from the page.

The input fields have `id` attribute assigned to them which could be used to extract these elements.

```
<input ... id="username" ...>
<input ... id="password" ...>
```

You may use query selectors for that:

```
# Extract username input field
const usernameInputField = document.querySelector('#username')

# Extract password input field
const passwordInputField = document.querySelector('#password')
```

In the above snippet, [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is used to extract any DOM elements from the webpage. This function takes in the [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) as a parameter. Here, `#username` and `#password` are the CSS selectors for username and password fields respectively. The `#` sign signifies to select using the DOM element's ID.

Once we have the input fields, all we are left to do is to get the current values from these fields:

```
# Get current input value of username input field
const username = usernameInputField.value

# Get current input value of password input field
const password = passwordInputField.value
```

We use the `value` property of the input element to grab the current input value.

### Solution:

```
// Grab the input fields from the page
const usernameInputField = document.querySelector('#username')
const passwordInputField = document.querySelector('#password')

function login() {
  // Grab current input values
  const username = usernameInputField.value
  const password = passwordInputField.value

  // The remaining code below stays the same
  if (username === a88, password === a89) {
    alert("Thành công")
  }
  else {
    alert("Không thành công")
  }
}
```

In the `login()` function, we take the current value of the input fields and do the validation as it was handled previously. Note that, we do that inside the function itself to ensure that we have the latest value from the input fields.

Answer (score 0):

The `document.getElementById()` method is used to select HTML elements by `id`. It is used as the rvalue of the `value` property to read the value of the HTML element.

```js
/* The following method is used to select HTML elements based on the id attribute. */
const userNameElem = document.getElementById('username');
const passwordElem = document.getElementById('password');
const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");

/* You can define the user name as a string as follows. */
const username = 'george';
/* You can define the user password as a string as follows. */
const password = '12345';

/* It is not recommended to assign a function to the "onclick" attribute in an HTML file. */
submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(userNameElem.value == username && passwordElem.value == password) {
    alert("TRUE");
  }
  else {
    alert("FALSE");
  }
});
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Input username" id="username" name="username" class="a47"><br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Input password" id="password" name="password" class="a47"><br>
    <button type="button" id="submit" class="login">Login</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code may help you. And I think [Web forms — Working with user data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms) will help you more.

```js
function login() {
    const username = document.getElementById("username").value
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value
    // I change "a88", "a89" to strings, not variables.
    // Change back if I'm wrong.
    if (username == "a88", password == "a89") {
        alert("Thành công")
    }
    else {
        alert("Không thành công")
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Login</h1>

<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Input username" id="username" name="username" class="a47">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Input password" id="password" name="password" class="a47">
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="login()" class="login">Login</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* "onclick"  function invoked from HTML file. */
 function submit() { 
  /* sample user name */
  const username = 'tony';
  /* sample password */
  const password = '1234';
  const userNameElem = document.getElementById('username');
  const passwordElem = document.getElementById('password');
  const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit");
  if(userNameElem.value == username && passwordElem.value == password) {
    alert("TRUE");
  }
  else {
    alert("FALSE");
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Input username" id="username" name="username" class="a47"><br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Input password" id="password" name="password" class="a47"><br>
    <button type="button" id="submit" class="login" onClick="submit()">Login</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can pass values to the functions as parameters within brackets. And also whenever you try to compare strings, use quotations to wrap your strings. In your case values of a89 and a88 should be within quotes.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Login</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<html>

<body>
  <h1>Login</h1>

  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Input username" id="username" name="username" class="a47">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Input password" id="password" name="password" class="a47">
    <br>
    <button type="button" onclick="login()" class="login">Login</button>

    <script>
      let username = 'username';
      let password = 'password';

      function login(username,password) {
        if (username === 'a88', password === 'a89') {
          alert("Thành công")
        }
        else {
          alert("Không thành công")
        }
      }
    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are not passing any argument to the function call. Also `a88` and `a89` are supposed to be variables not string literals.

Answer (score -3):

```js
<script>
  function login() {
    let username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    let password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if ((username == "a88", password == "a89")) {
      alert("Thành công");
    } else {
      alert("không thàng công");
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Also, please don't add garbage text to get around our quality filters.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.